# Angular ng-mock - help matching url routes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ngmock

I'm trying to use ng-mock to fake a DELETE request but keep getting Error: Unexpected request: DELETE /api/1.0/package/1. How do I properly define the mock url to match the factory request:

```
function deletePackage(file) {
  return $http.delete('/api/1.0/package/' + file.id)
    .then(deleteComplete)
    .catch(deleteFailed)            
}

$httpBackend.whenDELETE('/api/1.0/package/:id').respond(function(method, url, data, headers, params) {
   return [200, params.id];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So presumably you know what `file` argument you're going to pass to the `deletePackage` method. With that in mind, you should then know exactly what URI to expect.

```
var file = {id: 'some_id'};
$httpBackend.whenDELETE('/api/1.0/package/' + file.id).respond(file.id);

deletePackage(file); // presuming this function is in scope
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at the wrong version of the docs (1.5) and I had to remove the single quotes around the regex:

```
$httpBackend.whenDELETE(/\/api\/1.0\/package\/(.+)/)
.respond(function(method, url, data) {
   return [200];
});
```